# run() method of ISafeRunnable is not getting called when i used inside of org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job.Job(String name)

Tags: java

I have used org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job to schedule jobs.
I want to call run() method using ISafeRunnable

```
Job cmdJob= new Job("MyFile") {
                    @Override
                    protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor arg0) {
                        ISafeRunnable runnable = new ISafeRunnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void handleException(Throwable arg0) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void run() throws Exception {
                        System.out.print("I am inside run");
                    }
                    @Override
                    public boolean belongsTo(Object family) {
                        return false;
                    }

                };
```